# ANT to Maven Migration. Maven alternative to build.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, ant, build.xml

***Background***:

I am working on a open source tool called draw.io which is based on ANT build system and uses Java servelets to handle request. I am supposed to migrate it to spring boot with using same front end files. I put those files in static folder and tried to build the project. I figured that the front end js files were not getting build (i.e. were not getting converted to app.min.js, which is the main entry point for front end files), in the process and none of the js changes were getting reflected in the file.

I figured that this process was mentioned in build.xml as part of various steps which is ANT specific configuration. Now, I have to achieve the same in maven as the migration process.

How do we convert build.xml to maven or what is the maven alternative of achieving the tasks mentioned in the build.xml as part of build process?

This is the high level view of build.xml:->

[image]

I am also providing the link of build.xml [here...](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/blob/master/etc/build/build.xml)

Please provide me with some direction.

Answer (score 1):

Before migrating to `maven`, I hope you understand why you are moving to `maven` from `ant`.

You should try for finding alternative plugins for the  relevant `ant` task. The below plugin might do what you are trying to achieve in `ant`

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.blutorange</groupId>
      <artifactId>closure-compiler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <!-- Base configuration for all executions (bundles) -->
        <baseSourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</baseSourceDir>
        <baseTargetDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</baseTargetDir>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <!-- Process all files in the "includes" directory individually-->
        <execution>
          <id>default-minify</id>
          <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <sourceDir>includes</sourceDir>
            <targetDir>includes</targetDir>
            <includes>**/*.js</includes>
            <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
            <closureLanguageOut>ECMASCRIPT5</closureLanguageOut>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>minify</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

> More details about the plugin : [closure-compiler-maven-plugin](https://github.com/blutorange/closure-compiler-maven-plugin)

There are few cases during my `ant` to `maven` migration, I came across some custom tasks which I was not able to find appropriate plugins.

I used [maven-antrun-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) which keeps existing `ant` tasks in maven.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        ...
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

> More details about how to use the maven antrun plugin : [See this
>   tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-ant-task)

Comment: Hi.. I tried to minify the files using closure-compiler-maven-plugin. But after going till some files it throws some errors related to strict mode like variables cant be declared in strict mode and then stops. I also added <closureWarningLevels><es5Strict>OFF</es5Strict></closureWarningLevels>
 <closureEmitUseStrict>false</closureEmitUseStrict> . But still it shows the same errors.

Comment: Please elaborate more on the error received. I also request you to post another question or update the current question based on what you have tried with elaborated error details.

Answer (score 0):

For Maven, you need a `pom.xml`. There you need to define and configure the plugins you need. If you have a specific procedure written in Ant that you want to reuse, you can call it with the Maven Antrun Plugin.

Generally, Maven is very different from Ant. You don't write procedural code, but configure plugins running in a lifecycle.

Comment: I already have a pom.xml as it is a spring maven project. The overview of what I need to achieve is mentioned in the image and basically I want to replicate the build.xml steps in maven.
What do you suggest is the preferred approach? 1. Run the build.xml with antrun or write custom plugins for the whole build process mentioned in the build.xml? If you look at the build.xml it's a fairly large file.

Comment: For many things like compilation and bundling there are already Maven plugins. Some other things you may need to write yourself, either as Maven plugin or with an Ant Snippet. If you run the whole build.xml with Antrun, then you have technically migrated to Maven, but not really.